# Using Spark in while loop to process log files

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a server that generate some log files every 1 second and I want to process this file using Apache Spark.

I write a spark application using python and in a while loop I process a group of log files.

I stop sparkContext in each iteration and start it for next step.

My question is that what is the best approach for this kind of application that runs infinitely and process batches or group of generated files. should I use a infinite while loop or should I run my code in cron job or even scheduling frameworks like airflow?

Answer (score 3):

The best possible way to solve this is to use "Spark Streaming". Spark streaming enables you to process live data streams.Spark streaming currently works with Kafka,Flume,HDFS,S3,Amazon Kinesis and Twitter.Hence,you should first insert these logs into Kafka and then write a Spark streaming program which processes live stream of logs.This is a cleaner solution instead of using infinite loops and starting and stopping SparkContext multiple times.

Comment: I know your solution is more scalable and recommended. but I don't want add more layer to this part of my application. I use Kafka after this process and getting data from Kafka and write to database. what is wrong with using infinite loop? does this approach have any cons ?

Comment: Then instead of infinite while loop,a little better approach would be to use a scheduler like Quartz/airflow.But I would still suggest to see if Spark Streaming can be used.

Comment: what is the problem of infinite loop ?

Comment: It really is a streaming app: embrace spark streaming. If you do use a while loop, do at least keep the same spark context for the whole session, as that will save on setup/teardown time.

you do not need to set up Kafka: spark streaming can scan a directory for new files and act on them. This is what you want. Just make sure that the half-written files don't get picked up —this is done in HDFS by renaming them after the log file is closed.

Comment: @SteveLoughran I have a question about spark streaming from you. consider I use spark streaming and it monitors my directory and if new file have been created, spark catches it, so If my code stop and then start again, does spark knows the last file it reads or it starts from beginning ?

Comment: aah, that I don't know. I'd have to look at the source to find out, and, as I don't have it in front of me, that'll be something for you to look at.

Comment: @HoseinEY, this could be something you would know already,sorry to comment on after this long, but to answer your question, Spark has a structured streaming with checkpointing so that even if you stop the app,upon restart it will resume from the last checkpoint .I am assuming the logs are being read from a source like kafka, thats when this answer is more fit.